# Programmatic login with liberty profile without password

Tags: websphere-liberty

I try to migrate our application from WAS 8.0 to Liberty Profile at the moment.
In our application I need the possibility to do a programmatic login without having the password of the user.
In WAS 8.0 this was done with the following code snippet:

```
import com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject;
import com.ibm.ws.security.core.ContextManagerFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.callback.WSCallbackHandlerImpl;

public class SecurityConfigJaasWasImpl implements ISecurityConfig {

   public Object doAsWithoutPwd(String user, String[] roles, final ISecuredCode code) throws Exception {
      final String mName ="doAs(String, String[], ISecuredCode)";
      Object ret = null;
      try {
         if (code != null) {
            ret = WSSubject.doAs(ContextManagerFactory.getInstance().login("REALM", user), new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
               /* (non-Javadoc)
                * @see java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction#run()
                */
               public Object run() throws Exception {
                  return code.run();
               }
            });
         }
      } catch (LoginException e) {
         throw new SecurityConfigException("Error login user " + user);
      }
}
```

Unfortunately the class ContextManagerFactory is not known in Liberty.
All examples for programmatic login with liberty profile are using WSCallbackHandlerImpl to do a Jaas login. But for that I need to know the password of the user.

Is there any possibility to do something similar to my WAS 8.0 code in liberty profile?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when porting our application from WAS-ND 7 to Liberty.  Unfortunately, there is no way to perform a programmatic login on Liberty without having access to the user's password.  I have an open PMR with IBM on this (25293,082,000), and I was told that the feature is "under consideration".  I also have an RFE open on this:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=100438